# sum row of columns together if columns meet certain criteria listed in adjacent column

Tags: r

Aim
Create new columns containing the row sum of drink_vol_1 and drink_vol_2 for each type of drink (1,2,3) as denoted in drink_type_1 and drink_type_2 respectively.

Desired output:

```
study_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
a <- c(100,0,0,300,0,0)
b <- c(0,500,300,0,500,0)
c <- c(0,125,1000,0,0,1250)

DF  <- data.frame(study_id,a,b,c)
```

Sample data:

```
study_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
drink_type_1 <-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
drink_vol_1 <- c(100,500,1000,100,500,750)
drink_type_2 <-c(NA,3,2,1,NA,3)
drink_vol_2 <- c(NA,125,300,200,NA,500)

drink_df  <- data.frame(study_id,drink_type_1,drink_vol_1,drink_type_2,drink_vol_2) 

drink_df <- drink_df %>% mutate_at(c('drink_type_1','drink_type_2'), as.factor)
```

My initial thought that the dataframe needed to wrangled into a different format. So I tried the following:

```
drink_pivot <- drink_df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c('drink_type_1','drink_type_2'), names_to = "drink", values_to = "drink_type")
```

However am drawing a blank as too where to go from there.

Comment: Did you try your code? `1 <-  ...` is not possible, you can't assign anything to a number.

Comment: RowSums would be calculated by row. It sounds as though you should be looking for an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. pivot longer using `.value` argument.
2. group and summarise
3. pivot wider using `names_prefix`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

drink_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("drink"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "drink"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>% 
  group_by(study_id, drink_type) %>% 
  summarise(drink_vol = sum(na_if(drink_vol,0), na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = drink_type, values_from = drink_vol, 
              names_prefix = "drink_vol_", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-contains("NA"))
```

```
  study_id drink_vol_1 drink_vol_2 drink_vol_3
     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1        1         100           0           0
2        2           0         500         125
3        3           0         300        1000
4        4         300           0           0
5        5           0         500           0
6        6           0           0        1250
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well as the code. When I have compiled my data set I get column headings drink_vol_1_day1 and drink_type_1_day1  The regex expression in the names_pattern fails to work as group1 = drink_vol_1 and group 2 = day1 It would be great to have an output drink_vol_day1 Is that possible to do with names_pattern and a corrected regex. Cheers 
@TarJae

Answer (score 2):

```
drink_df %>% 
   pivot_longer(-study_id, names_to = '.value', 
                names_pattern = '_(\\w+)_', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = study_id, names_from = type,
               values_from = vol, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  study_id   `1`   `2`   `3`
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1   100     0     0
2        2     0   500   125
3        3     0   300  1000
4        4   300     0     0
5        5     0   500     0
6        6     0     0  1250
```

in base R:

```
setNames(drink_df, sub('_(\\d+)', '.\\1', names(drink_df)))|>
   reshape(-1, dir='long')|>
   xtabs(drink_vol~study_id+drink_type, data = _)

        drink_type
study_id    1    2    3
       1  100    0    0
       2    0  500  125
       3    0  300 1000
       4  300    0    0
       5    0  500    0
       6    0    0 1250
```